# java spring boot app failed to passing zipkin trace info to rabbitmq

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I was working on an Ecommerce microservice-based application. HTTP request structure: frontend -> order -> shipping -> rabbitmq -> queue-master. The shipping container get the trace info from order but it doesn't pass along to rabbitmq. Is there any configuration I should do? I thought using "spring-cloud-starter-zipkin" will help me handle it effortlessly.

(tcpdump) shipping get post request with trace info:

```
 2018-05-11 14:52:47.225204 IP 172.18.0.1.55648 > 172.18.0.8.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:320, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 316382616 ecr 316382616], length 319:    HTTP: POST /shipping HTTP/1.1
 E..sF.@.@............`.PU5.6.f
 .....Y......
 ........POST /shipping HTTP/1.1
 Accept: application/json
 Content-Type: application/json
 X-B3-TraceId: a5a28c66a3557a66
 X-B3-SpanId: 94e11436dc6c4bee
 X-B3-Sampled: 1
 X-Span-Name: http:/shipping
 X-B3-ParentSpanId: 1a084fd84593e495
 User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_131
 Host: shipping
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Length: 79
```

shipping send out to rabbitmq missing tracing data.

```
 2018-05-11 14:52:47.228864 IP 172.18.0.8.34840 > 172.18.0.6.5672: Flags [P.], seq 3168203512:3168203740, ack 344352272, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 316382617 ecr  316375545], length 228
 E...;.@.@..............(......f.....Y=.....
 ................<.(....shipping-task........g.<.........O...application/json.UTF-8...<
 __TypeId__S...,works.weave.socks.shipping.entities.Shipment.........O{"id":"8b92ebba-d95d-4212-af3e-6304ba5fc363","name":"57a98d98e4b00679b4a830b2"}.
```

EDITED:
Some code about post shipping request: (shipment is just an object with id and name)

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(value = "/shipping", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
Shipment postShipping(@RequestBody Shipment shipment) {
    System.out.println("Adding shipment to queue...");
    try {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("shipping-task", shipment);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to add to queue (the queue is probably down). Accepting anyway. Don't do this " +
                "for real!");
    }
    return shipment;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can share a simple Spring Boot project to let us to reproduce? Because RabbitMQ Binder Producer maps all headers to send: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbit_producer_properties. See `headerPatterns`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan This is the relevant code about that request. I don't know how to extract a simple project through. Could you see any parts that might be wrong? Should I add in related tracing field in the shipment object itself?

Answer (score 0):

OK! I see now the problem!

So, you say that your HTTP request has these tracing headers: `X-B3-TraceId`, `X-B3-SpanId`, `X-B3-Sampled`, `X-Span-Name`, `X-B3-ParentSpanId`.

Then you have this code:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("shipping-task", shipment);
```

And that's absolutely natural that your tracing header are not transferred to the RabbitMQ: there is just no those headers to send.

I believe that you can extract those headers in this `@RequestMapping` method and populate them to the AMQP message before sending. See `org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageBuilder`.

I also think that Spring Cloud Sleuth should have some mechanism to obtain those headers, e.g. `Tracer.currentSpan()`: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.0.0.RC1/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_current_span

Comment: In the guide link you provided above, I read through and find that they said they instrumented the rabbit template automatically. Since propagating the trace to next service need to generate a new span id, I do think they have this integration built in. Maybe I need to do something when request comes in to notify their instrument library?

Comment: Yeah. I see. Here it is: https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/master/instrumentation/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/brave/spring/rabbit/TracingMessagePostProcessor.java. Would you mind to check in the debug mode that it is definitely instrumented?

Comment: The application is running in Linux cluster so I don't have a debug tool like STS. Also since it's a microservice architecture, it cannot run this shipping functionality on its own. Any other suggestion? Logically since there is no trace info coming out, this instrumentation function should be failing.

Comment: Yeah... Correct. Do you have Spring Cloud Sleuth dependency in that microservice BTW? The fact you trace info in the HTTP request, doesn't mean that proper dependency is on place for the further tracing.

Comment: Yeah that's the first thing I checked. The dependency is fine but I didn't have anything related to sleuth/brave imported in that function file. The spring rabbit template is imported of course through. BTW thanks so much for answering my question here!